# Why are direct flights more expensive than connecting

Tags: air-travel, ana

I am an American living in Tokyo. I plan to go back to the US (NYC) to visit my family and for Christmas and New Year. Flights from Tokyo Narita to JFK on ANA (return) are $1,400. Of course this is too expensive. However, when I checked flights from Manila to New York, it was $600 return, on ANA's site and using the same NRT-JFK and back $1,400 flights. When I find flights from Tokyo to Manila, they were $500 return (on ANA as well). Sure, $1,100 is less than $1,400, but this is still expensive. Why is this? Also, can I book the MNL-JFK flights for $600 and not get on the flights to and from Manila?

Comment: Just in case someone asked, I have ANA miles, and flights from Haneda are more expensive than Narita.

Comment: Airlines will sell their tickets for what they think the market will bear, and prices will vary according to anticipated and actual demand. If you think the prices are too high then wait. They might drop. I don't understand your question about flights to Manila. If you're in Tokyo, how will a flight to Manila help you without a connection. to Japan?

Comment: Look up “hidden city ticketing”. A direct flight is more convenient: it’s quicker, involves less hassle, and less risks of delays. That’s the reason it’s more expensive. And no, you can’t skip flights on a ticket, if you do all subsequent flights will automatically be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are direct flights more expensive than connecting

Because the airline want to make more money. They feel that a non-stop flight is more valuable to the customer than a connecting flight hence they can charge more even though their own cost is significantly less.

Airlines typically don't charge based on cost but mainly on "what price we can get away with" using complicated revenue optimization systems. There are dozens of different prices for the same seat on the same plane.

> Also, can I book the MNL-JFK flights for $600 and not get on the flights to and from Manila.

Typically no but it's complicated. This practice is called **"hidden city ticketing"** or **"skiplagging"** and you can google on how it works and what you can and cannot do. In short: it violates the terms and condition of your contract. If you don't a fly any leg or your itinerary the airline will immediately cancel the rest of your flights, so you can only do it on the last leg. It also doesn't work with checked baggage.